# Docker and Active Directory Integration

Tags: docker

I haven't found any information on integration with MS Active Directory.  I use Vintela on Linux systems to authenticate with my AD servers.  If I were to have a large Docker server, I could probably configure Vintela on the host system but could it be set up inside of each container?  I'll need to maintain control over my user groups.  Users will only be able to access specific containers using their AD credentials and not needing to have any special configurations on their systems (this includes special accounts or certificates to access containers).

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I haven't used Vintela but with Docker you could use supervisord to launch both your application and Vintela. As part of your base Docker image you could have supervisord configured with Vintela, then add additional packages and supervisord configuration files to launch the application of each image. More details on the basics of supervisord configuration here:

https://docs.docker.com/articles/using_supervisord/

Let me know if anything about this is unclear and I will do my best to update my answer.

Comment: With Vintela, I need to add each system to AD and configure it before users can log in with AD credentials.  I think for any solution involving Vintela, I would need to have each container registered in AD.  I'm not familiar enough with Docker, but do containers look like a unique system?

Comment: For most purposes, yes. They run their own pared down operating system, and their own processes. If you run a process in a container that registers somewhere, registering another copy of that image (i.e. a second container) will result in 2 unique registrations.